What's the default process for an address to be designated as 'primary'?
I have a membership sign-up form which asks for two postal addresses, type 1 and type 2. What I'm seeing is that the first address in the form appears to be automatically designated as the primary address for the resulting contact record. I want the second address to be the primary address. Is it simply a case of changing the order of the form, or is there something that I'm missing?
I can see that in the list of location types one is set as the default, but that seems unrelated?

is it a setting in the Profile fields?

In the profile I can choose the location type, including the 'Primary' option, but what I need is for the address to be both primary and set to the location type that I've designated.

ah. i see. don't know. my first random thought would be if this is not possible out of the box, and you don't want custom js, then perhaps you can pass them on to a second FB based form to make that bit. clumsy but maybe doable without code

I think there is an issue here in that, as an administrator I can choose to set any existing address to be both the 'primary' (or for that matter the 'billing') address, and for it also be any given location type. i.e. there are two sets of options working alongside each other. But the profile config lumps all location options in together so only one can be applied. Some might call this a bug.
